Interior and closure of sets on metric spaces combined $ A, A^{\circ}, \overline{A^{\circ}}, \ldots $
For $ A \subseteq X $ where $ X $ is a metric space, the following sets can be formed:
$ A, A^{\circ}, \overline{A^{\circ}}, ( \overline{A^{\circ}} )^{\circ}, \ldots $ and $ \overline{A}, ( \overline{A} )^{\circ}, \overline{( \overline{A} )^{\circ}}, \ldots $
a.) Show: This system of sets consists of at most 7 different sets.
b.) Find an example $ A \subseteq X $, where indeed 7 different sets occur.
I've been struggling with this for a while now. I firstly tried to construct the example first to understand it better, so that $ ( \overline{A^{\circ}} )$ and $( \overline{A} )^{\circ}$ are different but this gets messy really fast. I just couldnt find a good way to start this problem so im very glad for any help.

This has a similar flavor to Kuratowski's closure-complement problem. (Wikipedia) No guarantees, but maybe some insights in solving yours can be found from looking at how it was solved.

Since interior is complement of closure of complement (and since closure is idempotent and complement is involutive), your system of sets is exactly the ones in Kuratowski’s closure-complement problem when the complement is applied even number of times, so exactly half of those, that is, at most $7$ different sets. Furthermore, the example in @PrincessEev ’s comment for Kuratowski’s closure-complement problem also provides an example for your answer.

Here is a more explicit argument:
Note that taking closure and taking interior are both idempotent, so we may assume the operations are taken alternately. Now observe the following facts:
$$\overline{\overline{A^\circ}^\circ} = \overline{A^\circ}$$
$$\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}^\circ = \overline{A}^\circ$$
Both are straightforward to verify. But this means the length of applying the operations, without producing repetitions, cannot exceed $3$, so there are at most $7$ different sets in your collection of sets, namely,
$$A, \overline{A}, \overline{A}^\circ, \overline{\overline{A}^\circ}, A^\circ, \overline{A^\circ}, \overline{A^\circ}^\circ$$
Now, the same example as in the Wikipedia article for Kuratowski's closure-complement problem shows that all seven can be different. Namely, let $A = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2) \cup \{3\} \cup ([4, 5] \cap \mathbb{Q})$. Then,
$$\begin{split}
A &= (0, 1) \cup (1, 2) \cup \{3\} \cup ([4, 5] \cap \mathbb{Q})\\
\overline{A} &= [0, 2] \cup \{3\} \cup [4, 5]\\
\overline{A}^\circ &= (0, 2) \cup (4, 5)\\
\overline{\overline{A}^\circ} &= [0, 2] \cup [4, 5]\\
A^\circ &= (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)\\
\overline{A^\circ} &= [0, 2]\\
\overline{A^\circ}^\circ &= (0, 2)
\end{split}$$

Here is a proof of the two facts I mentioned at the beginning:
For $\overline{\overline{A^\circ}^\circ} = \overline{A^\circ}$, first, since $\overline{A^\circ}^\circ \subset \overline{A^\circ}$ and the latter set is closed, we must have the closure of the former is contained in the latter, that is, $\overline{\overline{A^\circ}^\circ} \subset \overline{A^\circ}$. Conversely, $A^\circ$ is an open subset of $\overline{A^\circ}$, so $\overline{A^\circ}^\circ \supset A^\circ$. Taking closures of both sides, we have $\overline{\overline{A^\circ}^\circ} \supset \overline{A^\circ}$. Thus, $\overline{\overline{A^\circ}^\circ} = \overline{A^\circ}$.
The proof of the second fact $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}^\circ = \overline{A}^\circ$ is similar: $\overline{A}^\circ \subset \overline{A}$ and the latter set is closed, so $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ} \subset \overline{A}$. Taking interiors of both sides, we have $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}^\circ \subset \overline{A}^\circ$. Conversely, $\overline{A}^\circ$ is an open subset of $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}$, so $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}^\circ \supset \overline{A}^\circ$. Thus, $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}^\circ = \overline{A}^\circ$. (Alternatively, you could also prove the second fact by applying the first fact to the complement of $A$.)

Hey, first of all thanks for the argument. I feel like im missing an obvious characteristic of closure and interior because i seem to cannot prove the two statements you mentioned were pretty straightforwarded to verify at the beginning, i searched how Kuratowski did it, but only got some french results. If you could elaborate on that i would be very thankful.

@MarcelDavis, there should be other sources as well, but first result of search of "C. Kuratowski, Sur l'operation A de l’Analysis Situs, Fund. Math., 3 (1922), 182–199." gave me English translation by Mark Bowron.

@MarcelDavis I edited my answer to add at the end a proof of those two facts.

@DavidGao I tried doing it like that, but i had a problem with: "the closure of the former is contained in the latter", how would you argument that this is true? Because we know that ikiA =/ iA can be true (k = closure i = interior). Here is where i feel like im overlooking something easy.

@MarcelDavis If $A \subset B$ and $B$ is closed, then the closure of $A$ is a subset of $B$.

@MarcelDavis Dually, if $A \subset B$ and $A$ is open, then the interior of $B$ contains $A$. All of these are just the definitions of closure and interior.

ohh yes because the closure is the smallest such set so it cant be bigger. Damn, i really appreciate ur patience with me and thanks for ur answers.
